# Change DB2 Select query to sql Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2-400

I am migrating my application from `DB2` database to `sql server 2008`, for this I have to replace some queries according to sql server.

My query is:

```
SELECT '' 
       || table1.openid AS OPENID, 
       table2.mfg_part_no, 
       table2.description, 
       binnumber, 
       storageid, 
       tracktime, 
       table1.userid 
FROM   table1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 
              ON table2.openid = table1.openid 
       LEFT JOIN table3 
              ON table3.locationid = table2.locationid 
WHERE  value = '14' 
       AND field = 'STATUSID' 
       AND tracktime > '2012-01-01 00:00:00.00' 
       AND tracktime < '2014-01-02 00:00:00.00'
```

how can I write this query in sql server?

Comment: what error does it give you if you try and run it?

Comment: It gives following error.
Incorrect syntax near '|'.

Comment: You probably want `tracktime >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00`, or you'll skip anything that comes in at midnight.  If you're trying for 2 years worth of data, you actually want `< '2014-01-01'` - what you have now is getting you 2 years _and a day_.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
SELECT cast(table1.openid as varchar(255)) AS OPENID, 
       table2.mfg_part_no, 
       table2.description, 
       binnumber, 
       storageid, 
       tracktime, 
       table1.userid 
FROM   table1 
       LEFT JOIN table2 
              ON table2.openid = table1.openid 
       LEFT JOIN table3 
              ON table3.locationid = table2.locationid 
WHERE  value = '14' 
       AND field = 'STATUSID' 
       AND tracktime > '2012-01-01' 
       AND tracktime < '2014-01-02' ;
```

The only DB2 specific thing I see is the string concatenation operator.  I also removed the time component from the dates.  That shouldn't be needed in either database.